# WPF doesn't honor Textbox.MinLines for Auto height calculation

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, layout, textbox

I want to have a TextBox which Height grows as Iam entering lines of Text.

I've set the Height property to "Auto", and so far the growing works.
Now I want that the TextBox's Height should be at least 5 lines.
Now I've set the MinLines property to "5" but if I start the app the TextBox's height is still one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the MinHeight property.

Comment: Thanks! Fast and precise answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

A hack to make the MinLines property work

```
public class TextBoxAdv : TextBox
{
    bool loaded = false;


    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public TextBoxAdv()
    {
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler( Control_Loaded );

        SetResourceReference( StyleProperty, typeof( TextBox ) );
    }


    void Control_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        if( !loaded )
        {
            loaded = true;

            string text = Text;
            Text = "Text";
            UpdateLayout();
            Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better answer, thank you. It even retains bindings.

Comment: How is this used? I'm new to C#/WPF

Comment: @Chris The basic usage in XAML is: <YourNamespace:TextBoxAdv />
See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_custom_controls.htm for a detailed example

Comment: You have to be careful that the initial value isn't already "Text" or it won't trigger.  A solution to that is to always set it back to the same value but with something else appended. For example, `Text = text + "A"`.  That guarantees it will always be different.  Watch out though as this will also update all relevant bindings which may cascade unintentional changes down through your model, including possibly setting things to a 'dirty' state.  Check out my answer where I address all of the above, including not needing to manually use the `Loaded` event as well as not being a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a different solution that properly respects the `MinLines` property, rather than forcing you to use `MinHeight`.

First, start with a convenience method to allow you to `Post` an action to the window loop. (I'm including both one where you need to pass state and one where you don't.)

```cs
public static class Globals {

    public static void Post(Action callback){

        if(SynchronizationContext.Current is SynchronizationContext currentContext)
            currentContext.Post( _ => callback(), null);
        else{
            callback();
        }
    }

    public static void Post<TState>(TState state, Action<TState> callback){

        if(SynchronizationContext.Current is SynchronizationContext currentContext)
            currentContext.Post(_ => callback(state), null);
        else{
            callback(state);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, create an extension method for `TextBox` to 'initialize' the proper size based on `MinLines`.  I put this in a `Hacks` class because to me, that's what this is and it clearly identifies the code as such.

```cs
public static void FixInitialMinLines(this TextBox textBox) {

    Globals.Post(() => {

        var textBinding = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)?.ParentBinding;

        if (textBinding != null) {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty);
            textBox.UpdateLayout();
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty, textBinding);
        }
        else {
            var lastValue = textBox.Text;
            textBox.Text = lastValue + "a";
            textBox.UpdateLayout();
            textBox.Text = lastValue;
        }
    });
}
```

The above code handles both bound and unbound `TextBox` controls, but rather than simply changing the value like other controls which may cascade that change down through the bindings, it first disconnects the binding, forces layout, then reconnects the binding, thus triggering the proper layout in the UI.  This avoids unintentionally changing your bound sources should the binding be two-way.

Finally, simply call the extension method for every `TextBox` where `MinLines` is set.  Thanks to the `Post` call in the extension method, You can call this immediately after `InitializeComponent` and it will still be executed after all other events have fired, including all layout and the `Loaded` event.

```cs
public partial class Main : Window {

    public Main() {

        InitializeComponent();

        // Fix initial MinLines issue
        SomeTextBoxWithMinLines.FixInitialMinLines();
    }

    ...
}
```

Add the above code to your 'library' of functions and you can address the issue with a single line of code in all of your windows and controls.  Enjoy!